# Getting "Sender Address Rejected" Error in OpenProject Email Notification settings in configuration.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rubygems, yaml, openproject

I am trying to setup 'Openproject' management tool in Amazon AWS EC-2 instance. Everything is done and I am able to access openproject home page on entering the IP address of EC-2, but while registering for new user I am getting an error page.

After checking production.log file in the openproject files I am seeing the following error.

> Net::SMTPFatalError (553 5.7.1 : Sender
>   address rejected: not owned by user user@jayrobotix.com

Here are the settings in my configuration.yml file.

```
default:   # Outgoing emails configuration (see examples above)  
email_delivery_method:     :smtp   
smtp_address:               smtp.jayrobotix.com  
smtp_port:                  587   
smtp_domain:                jayrobotix.com   
smtp_authentication:       :plain   
smtp_user_name:             "user@jayrobotix.com"   
smtp_password:              "password"   
smtp_enable_starttls_auto:  false
```

The smtp_user_name and smtp_password is my username and password for my email server.

I am following the manual given in openproject.org website for configuring openproject in linux.

Please help me in setting up this.

..
Thanks

Comment: Solved the issue. Openproject was successfully installed without any issues. I just have go to administration and change the SMTP settings to send the mails from proper mail Id. I just overlooked that part and was struggling with the configuration.yml. file. Thanks Anyways....